# CSS linear opacity

Tags: css

I want to create some flat-UI-like blocks but I need a little help. I got through some guides with linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255,255,255,0) ,rgba(255,255,255,1)); and so on, but I have't found what I actually need.

Is there any way, how to do any layer with linear opacity? I have quite huge database of images, (so I definitely can't photoshop them to have opacity by itself), and I am loading it into many "div" as a background-image. But I need to make the divs to start beeing transparent in about 75% of its width.

Is it somehow possible in CSS?

There is what I need to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid something like that is not possible using CSS. Since you have many images, and provided you don't show too many of them at once, you can consider using `canvas` to render the opacity to each image:

http://jsfiddle.net/u256zkha/

Comment: Well, I will accept your answer as solution, maybe it will be usefull for someone else, but ... as I said in main post, I have lots of them. It is an image gallery - images marked as favourite from a gallery, to be specific. And user can have lots of them .. so even if the pictures thumbs are only about 300x300 px, that "for cycle" I don't like here very much. Anyway, thanks for help and your time :)

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I know it's off-topic and could perform badly with tons of images, but it was the only way I could think of doing that. That for-cycle is a standard when doing any kind of image manipulation on the canvas and it's fine on its own, but as I said, problem might arise as the number of images arises. You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can set a linear gradient background with an extra stop to make an element transparent for 75% of its width, then linearly increase opacity.

For example:

```
background: linear-gradient(
   to right, 
   rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,
   rgba(0,0,0,1) 75%,
   rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%
);
```

This makes an element have an opaque black (the three first rbga values) background for 75% of its width, then linearly transition to transparent in its rightmost 25%.

Comment: @Shomz: The question says "make the divs start being transparent", so I'm not sure that will be a problem. In any case, it's trivial to wrap images or whatever else in an extra div and work with the div.

Comment: yep, that I have already tried ... style=\"background-image:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%), url("+item.header.thumb+");\ and style=\"background-image:url("+item.header.thumb+") , linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%) ;\" both doesn't work. As I said, I have already tried to google it, bothering other people is an option only if plan A fails :) (ignore the slashes, it is from Javascript)

Comment: I was refering to `"how to do any layer with linear opacity? I have quite huge database of images"`, OP uses divs with background images and needs only gradual opacity drops.

Comment: even warped to another div, still the same question. Because even if I make the div, in which is warped my backgrounded div, linear-gradient-transparent, it will be still only background, not the div itself

Comment: aaand zep .. isn+t working with `<div style=\"background:linear-gradient(to right,rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 75%),\"><div class=\"favItemFoto\" style=\"background-image:url("+item.header.thumb+");\"></div></div>`

Comment: @Zorak perhaps I have misunderstood the question? An example graphic would clear things up.

Comment: @Zorak, you need to place the div with the gradient above (or inside) the one with the image.

Comment: @jcaron nope, not working, tried both ways, gradient div INTO BG div, , same size, no effect. Gradient div over BG div, also nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Using `linear-gradient`, partly from Jon's answer.

```css
#parent{
  position:relative;
  width:fit-content;
}
#layer{
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(
   to right, 
   rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,
   rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,
   rgba(0,0,0,0) 100%
);
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="layer"></div>
  <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=356&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1"/>
</div>
```